# Why id of a python variable is changing if it is less than -6

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have just came across a weird behavior while checking the `id` of a variable assignment. I had run following code

```
a = -5
print(id(a))
```

and got id as follows

```
140710231913104
```

I get the same `id` while executing Jupyter cell many times if `a >= -5` whereas, if I assign and run `a < -5`, I get different `id` each time after executing the Jupyter cell. Find summary in below image

[image]

What could be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: The cause of this is internal optimization in the CPython interpreter. It is nothing you should rely on in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at below example:

```
>>> a=256
>>> b=256
>>> print(id(a),id(b))
(31765012, 31765012)
>>> 
>>> c=257
>>> d=257
>>> print(id(c),id(d))
(44492764, 44471284)
>>>
```

This will help you understand the unexpected behaviour for integers. Whenever you create a Int in range -5 to 256 you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. This is called Integer Caching in python.

Comment: Can you please provide any reference to this?

Comment: This is for python3, In CPython, the C-API function that handles creating a new int object is `PyLong_FromLong(long v)`. see the documentation on https://docs.python.org/3.6/c-api/long.html

Answer (score -1):

From `help(id)`:

> id(obj, /)
>   Return the identity of an object.
>   This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
>   (CPython uses the object's memory address.)

For small numbers (not exactly sure how small), python only keeps one "version" of each number in memory. This is why every time you assign `-5`, you get the same memory location. When you assign `-6`, the address changes. If you try a larger number, you will get different results each time. Example:

```
>>> a = 9999999999999999999999; id(a)
140517821614080
>>> a = 9999999999999999999999; id(a)
140517821497216
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the id stays the same every time he assigns `a = -5` but changes every time he assigns `a = -6`.